# How to stop Android from scrolling to the end of an EditText when the text is selected?

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext

Be default, in an `EditText`, when all the text is selected and it is larger than the size of the `EditText`, the text is scrolled to the end. Is there a way to override this behavior so that the text is selected but remains in the current position?

This default behavior can be seen in Google’s Contacts app.

1. Create a new contact.
2. Type a long number in the phone number field, something like `6521487754158895575569856552149211111111111111`.
3. Scroll to the beginning of the phone number.
4. Double-tap on the number to select the entire text.  The number will be selected and automatically scrolled to the end.

Answer (score 1):

I not sure if i understand very well, but i think  if you need to stop the scroll in edittext use this:

```
editText.setMovementMethod(null);
```

Comment: `editText.setMovementMethod(null)` makes it so that text cannot be selected at all (it also does prevent the text from scrolling to the end).  My guess is that there is some way to tweak the settings of the MovementMethod so that text can be selected but isn't scrolled, but I have not been able to figure out what it is.